# API 404's when I try to fetch related tags for the `bin` tag

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, tags

If you query the API for tags related to [bin]: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/bin/related?site=stackoverflow

this simply returns:

```
Invalid JSON returned and a 404.
```

([live demo](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-tags#tags=bin&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true))

But it should return:

```
{
  "items": [],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 8194
}
```

I guess an intrusion detection of some sort is working here?

Comment: Notes:  (1) Probably applies to other reserved-word tags, and to (2) other routes. (3) Might never be fixed since it's likely part of server config (4) Maybe can restrict allowed tag names? (doubtful). (5) Barring the aforementioned, it should definitely be in the API docs.

Comment: As a fix idea: add a doc section about this and add a character which will always be stripped?